# Self-reference in a Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have two models: User and Point.

Point belongs_to the user. Point has an 'amount'. I want to define a method in the Point model that will return the user's total points. I'd like to call it in such a manner: `user.points.total`

I just don't know how to define the method in the Point model in such a way that I don't have to pass it the User's ID. I'd imagine there is a simple way to do this, but my Googlefu is failing me.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that User model has

```
has_many :points
```

you can do like this in User model

```
def total_points
    points.sum(:amount)
end
```

Comment: That was my first instinct, but I'd rather reference it like `User.points.total` instead of `User.total`. Thanks though!

Comment: @TheSciz I see nothing wrong in `user.total_points`, but you can accomplish what you want with [Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want the method defined in the `Point` model, you'd want to use:

```
class Point
  def total
    user.points.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

You can then get the total points for the user associated with a given `point` by invoking `point.total`.  You can't get total points through `User.points.total` because `User` is a class and doesn't refer to a particular user.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Using this method, I'm getting the following error trying to call it using whateveruser.points.total: `undefined method `total' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your comment carefully. Since you asked for a method within `Point`, you need to invoke this through an instance of `Point`.

Comment: If you want to invoke it through an instance of `User`, then the other answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [#sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum), which uses SQL sum to do an aggregation.

For example,

```
person.points.sum('amount')
```

or

```
# inside User.rb
def total
  points.sum('amount')
end
```